# How to export .sql file in MySQL database using MySQL commandline client?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

How to MySQL server database export .sql file using command line?

I have used below commands,but shows in syntax error

```
mysqldump -h ipaddress -u username -p password> mysqlfile.sql
```

I have below Error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
```

corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysq
dump -h 192.268.1.17 -u root -p root> mysqlfile.sql' at line 1